# Laravel API authentication redirects to login instead of simple 401 page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5.34 and it's my first time creating an API.

I've added an `api_token` column to the users table and generated tokens on registrations.

Later, I opened the `routes/api.php` file and added the following code:

```
Route::middleware( 'auth:api' )->get( 'test', function( Request $request ){
    dd( \Auth::user() );
});
```

This code works fine when I send an `api_token` in the POST data, but if I don't send, it redirects to the login page instead of a 401 page, even though I send an `Accept: application/json` header.

How can I make it redirect to a 401 page?

Comment: Whats your client, how do you send the request?  Also send `content-type: application/json`

Comment: @Kyslik I'm using curl as client: `curl -X GET "http://localhost/api/test" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Answer (score 9):

Set header "Accept: application/json" must be  sufficiently.

Laravel 5.5  handle «AuthenticationException» in App\Exceptions\Handler.php
“unauthenticated” method. Its look like:

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    //dd($request);
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

In  “expectsJson” method https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_expectsJson, performs check that request has header “Accept” containing “json” pattern:

```
return isset($acceptable[0]) && Str::contains($acceptable[0], ['/json', '+json']);
```

So, you must check that you request actually return **true** on *$request→expectsJson()* call. Probably you make error when set Accept header in request.